# Теряются сессии после редиректа

Tags: сессия, php

Добрый день.

Имею такую вот запись:

```
$_SESSION['admin']['id'] = $res['id'];
header ('location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
index.php
echo $_SESSION['admin']['id'];
```

После редиректа в PHP 5.4 стали происходить странные вещи, сессия не сохраняется. Перед редиректом она имеет какие-либо значения, после уже пустая. error_reporting включен, там все пусто. Может, кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, стоит добавить

```
session_start();
```

перед вашим кодом?

Comment: На более древней версии пхп работает.

Comment: @Quiss, это на какой такой более древней? В доке заявлено, что данная функция введена с PHP4. А последние версии - PHP 5.5, 5.6.

Comment: Вопрос решился моей криворукостью) кука с сессией цеплялась на домен. А сайт был развернут локально.

Answer (score 0):

Установите хром и в режиме разработчика (f12) посмотрите, что с вашими сессиями (в ресурсах).